# Applescript loading a FileMaker Pro script from another DB file

Tags: applescript, filemaker

I need to export some data from a FMP file.
As far as I can see, Applescript cannot export data, but the built in FMP Scripting can.
So I need to tell AppleScript to run a FMP Script, and this works fine.
However, my problem is that the FMP script I need is not present in the FMP Databases I need to process.
So I would create a new DB, save my FMP scripts into it and then "fetch" the FMP script through AppleScript from this "container" DB, and execute it on another FMP DB file.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any hints

Comment: It sounds like you don't have script editing privileges on the main database file--is that correct? Are you able to add Table Occurrences from the main database file into the file that you do have access to using External Data Sources?

Comment: thanks for answer, as long as I'm in the same DB where the script is saved, all is clear and works fine. It is that I would like to run a script in DB-a, but the script is saved in DB-b, so I would like to tell FMP to run the DB-b script in the DB-a DB. In the mean time I learned that I can import the script from DB-b into DB-a, but sadly, I cannot do that using applescript, unless I use UI scripting, so this is what I will try next.